# Finding $\frac d{dz}\exp(\pi z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find $dw/dz$ when $w = \exp(\pi z^2)$

I find:

$w = \exp(\pi z^2) = \cos\pi z^2 + i \sin \pi z^2 = -1 + 0 = -1$
Then $dw/dz = 0$

Is this right?

Or is the answer simply: $ dw/dz = 2z \pi \exp(\pi z^2)$?

Comment: Your first attempt does not work because $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ (for real $t$, I think), but you're dealing here with $e^t$, (where $t$ is complex). $e^{it}$ is not the same as $e^t$.

Comment: To @dfeuer's parenthetical remark:  $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ holds for all $t\in \mathbb C$ (both sides are entire functions, and agree on the real line). To Siyanda: the biggest problem with your first attempt is that you plugged in $z=1$ (it seems) before taking derivative. This is an absurd thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because the exponential function, and $\pi z^2$ are both holomorphic functions, you can just use the chain rule as you have done. So your second answer is correct.